# PCIe Source And Destination Address for EDMA

Tags: linux, pci-express

I have **Designware(Synopsys) PCIe Controller** supporting both EP(End-Point) as well as RC(Root Complex) functions.For the implementation scenario, this controller will be configured as EP & RC will be a linux PC.

---

My case is: I simply want to transfer 4 Bytes from EP(PCIe Controller) to 
RC(Linux PC).So, what will be the  destination address in case of Memory write transaction from EP(PCIe Controller) to RC(Linux PC)?
Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: It's impossible to tell without a lot more information... If you're really interested in the "_destination_" address, then... it could be on your stack / heap?...

Comment: Hi, for the eDMA,both the source & destination address are needed for data-transfer. Now, I have PCIe EP on my board so I have source address for memory write but still I don't know what the destination address will be?

Comment: "_source address for memory write_"... do you mean "_read_"? We can't help you out with a lot more information about both your system and what you're really trying to accomplish... What have you tried? Did you try allocating some memory and using that as the destination ("_write_") address?

Comment: Typically, there would be a driver running on the Linux PC which expects the memory transfer from the EP either as an answer to a read request, or as an answer to some scheduled DMA. And as part of the read request or the DMA request it would have sent the destination for the memory write to the EP. So what is you driver, who has written it, and what else does it do? You can't just schedule a memory write from the EP and expect the Linux PC to understand that...